# How to use Devise in models or use "if user_signed_in?" for associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

**Issue:**  I have a "belongs_to" association for a buyer.id but I also want people who aren't signed in to be able to create orders.

So I only need the association **if** the user is signed in

**How can i do:**

```
belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User"
```

but have it only associate if a user is signed in.

**I have tried:**

```
belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User", if: @user.current_user(true)
```

didn't work

```
belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User", if: user_signed_in
def user_signed_in
  @user.current_user(true)
end
```

didn't work

And a few other iterations of this.

I am using Devise and it seems as if it doesn't work in the models this way like it does in controllers.

**In the controller, I have done this: (somewhat not relevant)**

```
if user_signed_in?
   @order.buyer_id = current_user.id
 else
   @order.buyer_id = nil
end
```

What can i do so the

```
belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User"
```

only associates when a user is signed in?

My buyer_id migration:

```
class AddBuyerIdToOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :orders, :buyer_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: AFAICT, unless you have a FK explicitly set in the database as `NOT NULL`, everything should work out of the box. `belongs_to` is not mandatory as most of Rails checks (read: it might be `nil`.)

Comment: I just added my buyer_id migration.  Nothing was explicitly set.  or am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up finding a SO post about something similar that just used a guest_user.

**This is the code I used - slightly/hardly altered:**

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
  end

  def current_or_guest_user
    if current_user
      if session[:guest_user_id] && session[:guest_user_id] != current_user.id
        logging_in
        # reload guest_user to prevent caching problems before destruction
        guest_user(with_retry = false).try(:reload).try(:destroy)
        session[:guest_user_id] = nil
      end
      current_user
    else
      guest_user
    end
  end

  # find guest_user object associated with the current session,
  # creating one as needed
  def guest_user(with_retry = true)
    # Cache the value the first time it's gotten.
    @cached_guest_user ||= User.find(session[:guest_user_id] ||= create_guest_user.id)

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound # if session[:guest_user_id] invalid
     session[:guest_user_id] = nil
     guest_user if with_retry
  end

privte

  def create_guest_user
    u = User.new(:name => "guest", :email => "guest_#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(100)}@example.com")
    u.save!(:validate => false)
    session[:guest_user_id] = u.id
    u
  end
```

Now no matter what, someone is a user even if a guest.  And can create an account after an order with their orders listed if same email is used and email is confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way, because the model has no idea about `signed_in` status. If you want to create orders without users you should add `optional: true` to association, because Rails validates presence of `belongs_to`, starting from 5th version.

```
belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User", optional: true
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  This would work but i ended up creating a solution so guests are always users and guests can create accounts and view their orders after making an order as a guest.